# Hide shipping methods for specific shipping class in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

Essentially I'm trying to make the flat rate method Id `flat_rate:7` **disabled** when there is cart items that have the shipping class "Roller" (ID `92`).

**This is the code I tried:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wf_hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2);

function wf_hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class($available_shipping_methods, $package)
{
    $hide_when_shipping_class_exist = array(
        92 => array(
            'flat_rate:7'
        )
    );

    $shipping_class_in_cart = array();
    foreach(WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values) {
       $shipping_class_in_cart[] = $values['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
    }

    foreach($hide_when_shipping_class_exist as $class_id => $methods) {
        if(in_array($class_id, $shipping_class_in_cart)){
            foreach($methods as & $current_method) {
                unset($available_shipping_methods[$current_method]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Shipping class ID **`92`** is the shipping class and I want to hide `flat_rate:7` for it.

My Site is this: http://www.minimoto.me/
WordPress: 4.8.4
WooCommerce: 3.1.1

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question

Comment: I have answered your question the. As you will see this can be done in a very simple way. please try it and give me some feed back on it. Thanks.

Comment: We have created a plugin to easily do this job. https://elextensions.com/plugin/conditionally-hide-woocommerce-shipping-methods-plugin/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update 2019:** You should try instead this shorter, compact and effective way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $class = 92;
    
    // HERE define the shipping method to hide
    $method_key_id = 'flat_rate:7';
    
    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ){
        // If we find the shipping class
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class ){
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted method
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

> Sometimes, you should may be need to refresh shipping methods going to shipping areas, then disable / save and re-enable / save your "flat rates" shipping methods.

**Related:** [Hide shipping methods for specific shipping classes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406909/hide-shipping-methods-for-specific-shipping-classes-in-woocommerce/56407287#56407287)

> **To find the shipping methods IDs and the shipping classes IDs see below…**

---

Update for many different shipping methods (related to your comments):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $class = 92;

    // HERE define the shipping methods you want to hide
    $method_key_ids = array('flat_rate:7', 'local_pickup:3');

    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        // If we find the shipping class
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class ){
            foreach( $method_key_ids as $method_key_id ){
                unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted methods
            }
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Tested and works…

---

**Finding the shipping class ID.**

1. In the database under `wp_terms` table:

Search for a term name or a term slug and you will get the term ID (the shipping class ID).

2. On Woocommerce shipping settings editing a "Flat rate", with your browser html inspector tool, inspect a shipping Class rate field like:

[image]

In the imput name attribute you have `woocommerce_flat_rate_class_cost_64`. So 64 is the ID for the shipping class.

---

**Get the shipping method rate ID:**

> To get the related **shipping methods rate IDs**, something like **`flat_rate:12`**, inspect with your browser code inspector each related radio button attribute **`value`** like:
>
> [image]

Comment: The code still works perfectly but I have one more question I didn't want to open up a whole new thread for. How would I change the code in order to hide multiple shipping methods for one specific shipping class? For now I'm doing this with multiple versions of 'add_filter' but I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

Comment: @NiklasBuschner You can do that in one unique function…

Comment: @LoicTheAzec Do you mind giving me a hint on how to do it? I tried it with $method_key_id = 'flat_rate:7', 'local_pickup:3'; but this didn't work.

Comment: @NiklasBuschner I have maid an update for you… check it

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec! Thanks for the code here, but how about a bit different scenario? How to SHOW particular method for one CLASS, but hide for the rest?

Comment: Code works, had to clear the shopping cart to make it work (clear WC sessions).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - is there any practical difference inbetween looping trough $package['contents']['data'] or through WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values?

Comment: @pacmanito Yes there is one: cart items can be splitted in multiple shipping packages, so the array sum of all $package['contents'] (shipping packages contents) is equal to WC()->cart->cart_contents.

Answer (score 3):

By tweaking LoicTheAztec's code (cheers), I was able to unset a shipping method for ***each package*** based on the shipping class of its contents, rather than the cart as a whole. Perhaps it will help someone else too:

```
// UNSET A SHIPPING METHOD FOR PACKAGE BASED ON THE SHIPPING CLASS(es) OF ITS CONTENTS
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach( $package['contents'] as $package_item ){ // Look at the shipping class of each item in package

        $product_id = $package_item['product_id']; // Grab product_id
        $_product   = wc_get_product( $product_id ); // Get product info using that id

        if( $_product->get_shipping_class_id() != 371 ){ // If we DON'T find this shipping class ID
            unset($rates['wbs:9:dae98e94_free_ups_ground']); // Then remove this shipping method
            break; // Stop the loop, since we've already removed the shipping method from this package
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

This code allows me to unset my 'Free UPS Ground' shipping if the package contains anything but 'Standard' items (shipping_class_id 371 in my case).

The scenario from the original post (disable method ***x*** if shipping class ***y***) would work like this:

```
// UNSET A SHIPPING METHOD FOR PACKAGE BASED ON THE SHIPPING CLASS(es) OF ITS CONTENTS
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach( $package['contents'] as $package_item ){ // Look at the shipping class of each item in package

        $product_id = $package_item['product_id']; // Grab product_id
        $_product   = wc_get_product( $product_id ); // Get product info using that id

        if( $_product->get_shipping_class_id() == 92 ){ // If we DO find this shipping class ID
            unset($rates['flat_rate:7']); // Then remove this shipping method
            break; // Stop the loop, since we've already removed the shipping method from this package
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```