# Remove duplicated shipping packages using a shipping class in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

The products in my website are handled by one of that 2 shipping plugins: [Printful Integration for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/printful-shipping-for-woocommerce/) and [Printify for WooCommerce Shipping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/printify-for-woocommerce/). when there is mixed items from each shipping plugin. Those plugins split each one the shipping package in two when there is mixed items *(which is a a conflict and a problem)*.

So I have added a shipping class **`'printful'`** *(which id is **`548`**)* to the products that are handled by the [Printful plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/printful-shipping-for-woocommerce/), and tried to adjust [Hide shipping method for specific shipping classes in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718180/hide-shipping-method-for-specific-shipping-classes-in-woocommerce/47732732#47732732) answer code by @LoicTheAzec (cheers), to only remove the shipping method from a specific duplicated shipping packages with ids 2 and 3 due to the conflict between the shipping plugins…

[image]

Here is my actual code:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $class = 548; //CAMDEN HARBOR CHART MUG is in shipping class

    // HERE define the shipping methods you want to hide
    $method_key_ids = array('printify_shipping_s', 'printify_shipping_e');

    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // If we find the shipping class
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class ){
            foreach( $method_key_ids as $method_key_id ){

                unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted methods
            }
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

But it's not working and I still get 4 shipping packages instead of two:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can't target `shipping_method_2_printify_shipping_s` as its just an html tag id… What you are targeting is `printify_shipping_s` or `printify_shipping_e` for the package ID 2. But for `woocommerce_package_rates` filter hook there is no way to target a specific package ID, so the code from my answer will not be useful in your case. I dont have the answer to your question and I can't help.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you for your insight and quick response. Basically I just want to remove 'Shipping 3' and 'Shipping 4' https://imgur.com/a/2HZRaCw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is related to splitting packages conflict between your two shipping plugins, when mixed items are in cart. In that case each plugin split the shipping package, which add 4 split packages instead of 2.

Those plugins are using `woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages` to split the shipping packages with an unknown priority `(so I will set a very high priority)`.

The following code will keep the first 2 split packages from cart (and checkout too):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', 'remove_split_packages_based_on_items_shipping_class', 100000, 1 );
function remove_split_packages_based_on_items_shipping_class( $packages ) {
    $has_printful = $has_printify = false; // Initializing

    // Lopp through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        // Check items for shipping class "printful"
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class() === 'printful' ){
            $has_printful = true;
        } else {
            $has_printify = true;
        }
    }

    // When cart items are mixed (using both shipping plugins)
    if( $has_printful && $has_printify ){
        // Loop through split shipping packages
        foreach( $packages as $key => $package ) {
            // Keeping only the 2 first split shipping packages
            if( $key >= 2 ){
                // Removing other split shipping packages
                unset($packages[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $packages;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should works and display only two shipping packages when cart items are mixed.