# Hide shipping methods for specific shipping classes in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

In WooCommerce, I am hiding shipping methods based on different shipping classes in cart using *"[Hide shipping methods for specific shipping class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718180/hide-shipping-methods-for-specific-shipping-class-in-woocommerce/47732732#47732732)"* answer code *(the 2nd way)*, but the problem is that I use WPML plugin which manage 2 languages site, so looking for just one class won't do it.

So I need to handle 2 shipping classes instead of one. I tried addind 2 shipping classes this way:

```
// HERE define your shipping classes to find
$class = 3031, 3032;
```

But it breaks the website. So I would like to hide the defined flat rate not only for both shipping classes **`3031`** and **`3032`**.

What I am doing wrong? How can I enable 2 shipping classes without breaking the web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use multiple shipping classes, you should first defined them in an array and in the **`IF`** statement you will use `in_array()` conditional function this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping classes to find
    $classes = [3031, 3032];

    // HERE define the shipping methods you want to hide
    $method_key_ids = array('flat_rate:189');

    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        // If we find one of the shipping classes
        if( in_array( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id(), $classes ) ){
            foreach( $method_key_ids as $method_key_id ){
                unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted methods
            }
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Sometimes, you should may be need to refresh shipping methods going to shipping areas, then disable / save and re-enable / save your "flat rates" shipping methods.

Related thread: [Hide shipping methods for specific shipping class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718180/hide-shipping-methods-for-specific-shipping-class-in-woocommerce/47732732#47732732)